# Amazon SES bounce on valid emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-bounces

I have an abnormal rate of bounce with Amazon SES. It's quite new. Some valid emails are tagged as bounce (and I know they are valid, I use them everyday in my personal email manager).

**My dkim and spf look valid in the Amazon interfac**e but there's obviously a problem somewhere.

Here is what I find in headers in a recipient managed by OVH :
X-Ovh-Remote: 54.240.4.25 (a4-25.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com)

X-Ovh-Tracer-Id: 14527486501045022689

X-VR-SPAMSTATE: DCE

X-VR-SPAMSCORE: 107

X-VR-SPAMCAUSE: gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrgedtuddrgedugddtiecutefuodetggdotefrodftvfcurfhrohhfihhlvgemucfqggfjpdevjffgvefmvefgnecuuegrihhlohhuthemuceftddtnecuufgvnhguhiculddutdejmd

X-Ovh-Spam-Status: OK

**X-Ovh-Spam-Reason: vr: OK; dkim: disabled; spf: disabled**

X-Ovh-Message-Type: DCE

Where should I give a look ?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. OVH told me they don't take care of DKim and SPF. I answered it is the reason they tag my emails, and they never replied anything.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Comment: Hello did you find the solution of this issue,

Comment: Everything is still the same here. But I see the question looks interesting for a few people and not only for me. Can you try to to give a +1 to up the matter ? I'm still interested in the answer.